# JS variable value from PHP array NOT bringing whole array values

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm developing a holiday summer house rental website with a Jquery datepicker calendar that disables unavailable dates based on a MySQL query.

```
<?php
$datos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE Status = 'Accepted' ");
?>
```

In order to calculate the disabled dates based on range of dates (checkin - checkout) I use a PHP code that calculates the dates in between and then puts those values in an array as follows:

```
<?php
while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)) {
    ?>
    <?php

// Declare two dates

    $Date1 = $user['Check_in'];
    $Date2 = $user['Check_out'];

// Declare an empty array

    $array = [];

// Use strtotime function

    $Variable1 = strtotime($Date1);
    $Variable2 = strtotime($Date2);

// Use for loop to store dates into array
    // 86400 sec = 24 hrs = 60*60*24 = 1 day

    for ($currentDate = $Variable1; $currentDate <= $Variable2;
        $currentDate += (86400)) {
        $Store   = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate);
        $array[] = $Store;}

// Display the dates in array format

    $finalvalue = $array;

// Write it to the output

    echo json_encode($finalvalue);?> <?php }?>

?>
```

$finalvalue outputs:

```
["2019-04-03","2019-04-04","2019-04-05","2019-04-06","2019-04-07", 
"2019-04-08","2019-04-09","2019-04-10","2019-04-11",  "2019-04-12","2019-04-13","2019-04-14"]   
["2019-04-24","2019-04-25"]
```

//////
Now in my JS for the datepickers:

```
var disabledDates = <?=  json_encode($finalvalue)?>;
console.log(disabledDates)
```

////// for some reason  finalvalue$ outputs only:

```
["2019-04-24","2019-04-25"] 

$("#checkin").datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1]
    },
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        $("#checkout").val(selected);
        $("#checkout").datepicker("option", {minDate: new Date(selected)})
        calcDiff();
    }
});
```

Why isn't JS bringing the whole string of dates as in the PHP first output?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are passing the variable in as a JSON encoded string but not parsing that data into a Javascript array? What if you did something like

`var disabledDates = JSON.parse(<?=  json_encode($finalvalue)?>);`

Comment: Just tried your code but now it doesn't bring any values.

Comment: Just took a closer look at your output for `$finalvalue`. You have 2 arrays in there. One of them has the first 12 dates, and the second one has the last 2. Is that a formatting error in your question, or an error in the code?

Comment: I just realized that if I remove:

// Declare an empty array

    $array = [];

It works with only one array.